# How do you see MVP records?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

How do you see the MVP of your past matches?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to look at that data in game; the only way you can see is at the end of replays or through a third-party replay analyzer like [HotsLogs](https://www.hotslogs.com/Player/Profile?PlayerID=346798), where you can see your overall MVP percentage (as long as you upload all your games, it would be accurate), along with the MVP in each of your games in the match history as shown below:

[image: MVP match log]